# Print 2D array - Diferent results Eclipse and PowerShell java

Tags: java, arrays, powershell, console, println

Basically I have a simple App that you insert the dimensions (x,y) of your 2D array and it will print its border on the console.
For example, if you insert 2 2 it will print:

```
----
|  |
|  |
----
```

This prints correctly in the Eclipse console and for example Windows PowerShell but if I run the app (using java -jar myApp.java) on Cygwin ou git bash the app prints:

2 2

```
----
||
||
----
```

The way I am printing is:

```
 String LINE_SEPERATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
 public void render() {
    StringBuilder drawnCanvas = new StringBuilder();

    for (int row = 0; row < this.canvas.length; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < this.canvas[row].length; col++) {
            drawnCanvas.append(this.canvas[row][col]);              
        }
        drawnCanvas.append(LINE_SEPERATOR);
    }
    System.out.println(drawnCanvas.toString());
}
```

[print of the actual consoles differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ono.png)

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?
Thanks

Comment: what does `this.canvas[row][col]` contain?

Comment: will contain - ou | to create the borders

Comment: @JamesMay Please show us the code that populates `this.canvas`

Comment: Your canvas array contains a whitespace character (probably just a space). Try populating it with a visible character and see if your border comes out correctly. If so then you know it has to do with how that console renders a space.